# Asymptotics claims (little o and exponentiation)

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

I have been stuck on this for hours and would really appreciate some help with it. I have to check if those statements imply the given outcome.

> a) $f(n)=o(g(n))$ implies that $3^{f(n)}=o(3^{g(n)})$
>
> b) $3^{f(n)}=o(3^{g(n)})$ implies that $f(n) = o(g(n))$

I am really having problem with this and would appreciate your help. here's what I did:

a) seems to be a true claim.since if $f(n)=o(g(n))$ then $0\leq f(n)<cg(n)$. so in this case $3^{f(n)} <c\cdot 3^{g(n)}$, which makes it a true claim.

b) here i really don't know. if $3^{f(n)}=o(3^{g(n)})$ then it should mean $3^{f(n)}< 3^{Cg(n)}=(3^C)^{g(n)}$. I don't know how to deduct from here whether it is a true claim or not.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You seem to be thinking of big-o not [little-o](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Little-ONotation.html)

Comment: @saulspatz the quantifiers on $c>0$ are missing. $\exists$ vs. $\forall$...

Comment: @ClementC. Aha!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the main takeaway here is *be careful with exponentiation and asymptotics*. It is not quite always what you'd expect.

---

a). This is **false**... first, a counterexample: $f(n) = \frac{1}{n}$, $g(n)=1$. We clearly have $f(n) = o(g(n))$ when $n\to\infty$. Yet,
$$
\frac{3^{f(n)}}{3^{g(n)}} = 3^{\frac{1}{n}-1} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \frac{1}{3} > 0
$$
so we actually have $3^{f(n)} = \Theta(3^{g(n)})$. 
*Why? $f(n)=o(g(n))$ does not mean much for $f(n)-g(n)$ (it could go to $-\infty$, or as above... to $0$. But that's the exponent of the ratio $\frac{3^{f(n)}}{3^{g(n)}}$.*

b). This is **false** again. $3^{f(n)} = o(3^{g(n)})$ (when $n\to\infty$) is equivalent to $3^{f(n)-g(n)} = \frac{3^{f(n)}}{3^{g(n)}} = o(1)$, that is 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} 3^{f(n)-g(n)}  = 0\,.
$$
By continuity of the logarithm, taking $\log$'s we get 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} (f(n)-g(n))  = -\infty\,.
$$
This does *not* imply $f(n) = o(g(n))$ either, only that the *difference* goes to $\infty$ (instead of the *ratio* going to $1$). For a counterexample:
$$
f(n) = n^2, \qquad g(n) = n^2+n\,.
$$

Comment: thank you very much for clarifying it to me. i should've done the ratio test and compare it o 0 to catch it's not true (regarding both)

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Recall that by definition

- $f(n) = o(g(n))\iff f(n)=\omega(n)\cdot g(n)$ with $\omega(n)\to 0$

then

- $3^{f(n)}=3^{\omega(n)\cdot g(n)}$

thus claim a) seems to be not true. Can you find a couterexample?

Try with $f(n)=\frac 1 {n^2}$ and $g(n)= \frac1n$.

For b) we have

- $3^{f(n)} = o(3^{g(n)})\iff 3^{f(n)}=\omega(n)\cdot 3^{g(n)}$ with $\omega(n)\to 0$

then

- $\log_3 3^{f(n)}=\log_3 (\omega(n)\cdot 3^{g(n)}) \implies f(n)=\log_3 (\omega(n))+g(n)$

thus also claim b) seems to be not true. Can you find a couterexample?

Try with $f(n)=\log_3 \frac 1 {n^2}$ and $g(n)= \log_3 \frac1n$.

Comment: A small comment on notation: writing $\omega(n)$ for a function which goes to $0$ is going to be **very** confusing in this context, as... $\omega(n)$ in the Banach-Landau family of asymptotics notation means "going to infinity much faster than $n$".

Comment: @ClementC. Thanks for your observation, what should you suggest to use instead of that.

Comment: $\varepsilon(n)$?

Comment: @ClementC. I'm used with $\omega$ since in my lectures we have always used that instead of $\epsilon$. Anyway, nice to know. Thanks

Comment: No problem. Again, it's a small comment.