# Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)/g(n)= 0 \implies \lim_{n\to\infty}3^{f(n)}/3^{g(n)} = 0?$ when both functions are monotone growing and positive

Tags: limits, functions

$f(n), g(n)$ are both monotone growing functions such that $f(n), g(n) > 1 \ \forall  n $.

How can  I prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}= 0 \implies \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3^{f(n)}}{3^{g(n)}} = 0?$$

Comment: Related (not exactly the same): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2716609/asymptotics-claims-little-o-and-exponentiation/2716631#2716631

Comment: It'd be nice if you told us what you have tried, thought about, considered...

Comment: General approach: $3^{f(n)}/3^{g(n)}=3^{f(n)-g(n)}$.  Since both are > 1, g(n) becomes infinite faster than f(n), so that $f(n)-g(n)\to -\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Detailed outline:** write $f(n) = \varepsilon(n)g(n)$, with by assumption $\lim_{n\to\infty}\varepsilon(n) = 0$. 
Then
$$
\frac{3^{f(n)}}{3^{g(n)}} = \frac{1}{3^{g(n)-f(n)}}
= \frac{1}{3^{(1-\varepsilon(n))g(n)}}\,.\tag{1}
$$
Since $x\mapsto 3^x$ is continuous, it suffices to prove that 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-\varepsilon(n))g(n) = +\infty\,.\tag{2}
$$
Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-\varepsilon(n)) = 1$, it suffices to prove that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} g(n) = +\infty\,.\tag{3}
$$
But this follows from our assumption that $f(n)\geq 1$ for all $n$:
$$
g(n) \geq \frac{g(n)}{f(n)} = \frac{1}{f(n)/g(n)} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \infty\,.
$$

---

Note that this would be false without the monotonicity assumption on $f,g$, as shown in [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2716609/asymptotics-claims-little-o-and-exponentiation/2716631#2716631).

Comment: This is a proof, not an outline. And why ask for the OP:s thoughts if you answer the question anyway?

Comment: @Sisyphus It started as an outline. (And though asking for the OP's input and providing an answer seem a bit weird, there is no formal inconsistency there. And, admittedly, I was bored.)

Comment: Sorry if this question is silly but how does the third point satisfies the proof? it follows that $3^{f(n)}/3^{g(n)}\to\infty?$ if so, how?

Comment: Because then $\lim_{n\to\infty } \frac{1}{3^{g(n)-f(n)}} = 0$, since $\lim_{n\to\infty} (g(n)-f(n)) = \infty$.